Type inference typescript
I have played around a lot with trying to build a SignalStoreFeature extension similar to withDataService from the angular architects. However I want to be able to pass in dynamic queryParams into the DataService functions. As it turns out I can only get the compiler to detect the type of these queryParams if I explicitly tell him the type. Is there a way to make the compiler indirectly notice the type of the queryParams.
Here is a simplified code example
type DataServiceQueryParams<S extends DataService<any, any>> = { [K in keyof DataService<any, any>]: Parameters<S[K]>[0] }
type Entity = {id: string}

interface DataService<E extends Entity, Q extends DataServiceQueryParams<any>> {
    loadAll(queryParams?: Q["loadAll"]): Promise<E[]>
    loadOne(queryParams?: Q["loadOne"]): Promise<E>
}

class Service implements DataService<{ id: string }, DataServiceQueryParams<Service>> {

    loadAll(queryParams: { assetId: string }): Promise<{ id: string }[]> {
        return new Promise(() => [{ id: '20' }]);
    }

    loadOne(queryParams: { assetId: string, id: string }): Promise<{ id: string }> {
        return new Promise(() => ({ id: '20' }));
    }
}

class Component<E extends Entity, Q extends DataServiceQueryParams<any>> {
    s: DataService<E, Q>;
    constructor(s: DataService<E, Q>) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}

// when passing in the DataServiceQueryParams<Service> it works
const x = new Component<{ id: string }, DataServiceQueryParams<Service>>(new Service());
x.s.loadAll({ assetId: '' }) // <- will complain that assetId is missing

// when not passing in types
const y = new Component(new Service());
y.s.loadAll({  }) // <- will not complain that assetId is missing

Is it even possible for typescript to do that?

Does this question depend on rxjs? If so, please tag the question as such so relevant experts get their eyes on it. If not, please [edit] the example code to remove its dependency on it, so it's a [mre] and people who are merely TS experts and not rxjs experts can more easily work on it. Good luck!

no it does not depend on rxjs. I removed it

There's at least one typo in your code; () => { id: '20' } is not valid. Please check your code in an IDE, and [edit] so that the only problems present are the one you're asking about.

(see prev comment) The problem is that TS cannot infer Q from Q["loadAll"] or from Q["loadOne"]. Inference of generics from indexes into them is not a feature of TS (maybe if https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53017 if ever merged it will be) If you want inference you need to split your generics apart as shown in this playground link (and note I just dropped your circular type definitions, including implements which isn't necessary). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz fixed the typo and yes that fixes my problem thank you very much

The problem is that your DataService<E, Q> type only refers to the generic type parameter Q via the indexed accesses Q["loadAll"] and Q["loadOne"].  But TypeScript cannot infer Q from those indexed accesses. It's a missing feature that was once implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#20126 but never merged into the language, and then implemented again more recently at microsoft/TypeScript#53017 but still not part of the language as of TypeScript 5.7.  If it ever gets merged then your above code might just start working as-is.
Until and unless that happens you need to work around it. Currently if you want to infer both Q["loadAll"] and Q["loadOne"] you'll need to refactor so that each one is its own generic type parameter, like LA and LO:
interface DataService<E extends Entity, LA, LO> {
  loadAll(queryParams: LA): Promise<E[]>
  loadOne(queryParams: LO): Promise<E>
}

Now you can write Service as-is (and note that you don't need an implements clause unless you're trying to check that Service is a valid DataService, and if you do do this, then you probably don't need it to circularly reference itself):
class Service {
  loadAll(queryParams: { assetId: string }): Promise<{ id: string }[]> {
    return new Promise(() => [{ id: '20' }]);
  }

  loadOne(queryParams: { assetId: string, id: string }): Promise<{ id: string }> {
    return new Promise(() => ({ id: '20' }));
  }
}

And make sure Component is generic in the new type parameters as well:
class Component<E extends Entity, LA, LO> {
  s: DataService<E, LA, LO>;
  constructor(s: DataService<E, LA, LO>) {
    this.s = s;
  }
}

And finally inference works as intended:
const y = new Component(new Service());
/* const y: Component<{
    id: string;
}, {
    assetId: string;
}, {
    assetId: string;
    id: string;
} */
y.s.loadAll({}); // error!
//          ~~
// Property 'assetId' is missing in type '{}'
//  but required in type '{ assetId: string; }'

Playground link to code
